# Add scoreboard to custom item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/execute @e[score_penguintime_min=99] ~ ~ ~ /summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"penguin",CustomNameVisible:1,IsVillager:0,IsBaby:1,Equipment:[{id:fish,Count:1},{id:leather_boots,Count:1,tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"penguin hide",Lore:[What can this do?],color:0}}},{id:leather_leggings,Count:1,tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"penguin hide",Lore:[What can this do?],color:16777215}}},{id:leather_chestplate,Count:1,tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"penguin hide",Lore:[What can this do?],color:16580351}}},{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"penguin head",Lore:[A penguin head!]},SkullOwner:{Id:"53c01f77-c4bd-458e-8fd8-70f7bb33dd5c",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvZDNjNTdmYWNiYjNhNGRiN2ZkNTViNWMwZGM3ZDE5YzE5Y2IwODEzYzc0OGNjYzk3MTBjNzE0NzI3NTUxZjViOSJ9fX0="}]}}}}],DropChances:[0.1F,0.4F,0.5F,0.4F,0.5F],Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:5},{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:0.3},{Name:generic.followRange,Base:0}],HealF:5,Silent:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:2000,ShowParticles:0b}]}
```

Why doesn't it work when I do

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] item 1 {Item:{id:leather_chestplate,tag:{display:{Name:"penguin hide",Lore:[What can this do?]}}}}
```

and

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] item 2 {Item:{id:skull,tag:{display:{Name:"penguin head",Lore:[A penguin head!]}}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you access pre-existing data (via commands like `/scoreboard` and `/testfor`), you're checking it as-is. The data you input will not be auto-corrected like it is with `/summon`, which includes correct tag-types as well as filling in missing information.

In this case, item IDs are saved with a namespace, defaulting to `minecraft`. As such, you must check for that exact item ID since the namespace will not be added in automatically with `/scoreboard`. The result is `minecraft:leather_chestplate` rather than `leather_chestplate`.

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] item 1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",tag:{display:{Name:"penguin hide",Lore:["What can this do?"]}}}}

/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] item 2 {Item:{id:"minecraft:skull",tag:{display:{Name:"penguin head",Lore:["A penguin head!"]}}}}
```